# #1452 MySQL Error: foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

These are the two db-tables:

1) kind_basis

```
id              bigint(20) unsigned     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
vorname         varchar(64)             NO          NULL    
nachname        varchar(64)             NO          NULL    
geburtsland_id  bigint(20) unsigned     YES MUL     NULL
```

2) liste_land

```
id              bigint(20) unsigned     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
iso             varchar(2)              NO          NULL    
landname        varchar(255)            NO          NULL
```

The db-table liste_land has the list of the countries (excerpt):

```
1   AD  Andorra
2   AE  Vereinigte Arabische Emirate
3   AF  Afghanistan
4   AG  Antigua und Barbuda
5   AI  Anguilla
6   AL  Albanien
7   AM  Armenien
8   AO  Angola  
    ....
```

This is the sql query:

```
 ALTER TABLE `kind_basis` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_geburtsland_id` 
        FOREIGN KEY ( `geburtsland_id` ) 
        REFERENCES `liste_land` (`id`)
```

This is the mysql error message:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`testing_v2.0.0`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-6687_13b16'>, 
CONSTRAINT `fk_geburtsland_id` FOREIGN KEY (`geburtsland_id`) REFERENCES 
`liste_land` (`id`))
```

I am doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in kind_basis table you have one or multiple rows with geburtsland_id  that don't have a match in field id of table liste_land.

Comment: can you run following query to be sure: select geburtsland_id  from kind_basis kb left join liste_land ll on kb.geburtsland_id = ll.id
where ll.id is null;

Comment: which is the parent-table kind_basis or liste_land?

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to add constraint over existing table i.e. kind_basis , **some rows present in that table are violating contraint which you are trying to add**. What you need to do is **first remove those values from kind_basis geburtsland_id's column which are not present in liste_land id columns**. Then you will succeed. Truncation of table is not the only available option, there are some more.

Comment: both of them is a correct answer, but I can set only one accepted answer.